# StringEscapeUtils cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, import, apache-commons-lang

I am currently attempting to access a code designed by another programmer in my company. My job is to take his code from the `jar` he designed and make it easier to use for those who are less technologically savvy.

The first time I tried to run the code, it seemed to run fine, but for some reason the second time, it gave me the following error:

```
"StringEscapeUtils cannot be resolved"
```

He has imported the above file and I have added `commons.apache-3 3.3.4` into my External Libraries on `Eclipse`, but still I can't get the program to even run. It doesn't tell me I have an error, but a red exclamation point appears by the package in the package browser.

I've never seen this error before. I know for a certainty that the other coder's program works exactly as he intended it. I have all of his code extracted into my eclipse. Is there any way at all to fix this error so that I can modify the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did all of those things. None of them made a difference. Then, I made a bat file out of the jar and, lo and behold, it edited cleanly from there.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using maven, try to clean the dependency in .m2 folder.
If not, go to project properties/Deployment assembly and add the lib folder there.

It should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The class in question belongs to the [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang) package. Try adding it to your project. If it uses [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/), add the following dependency in your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and simply restarting the apache server seemed to fixed it.